# Extension of a group $G$ by a commutative group $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, group-extensions

Let $F,G$ be two groups. An extension of $G$ by $F$ is a triple $\mathscr{E}=(E,i,p)$, where $E$ is a group, $i:F\rightarrow E$ is an injective homomorphism, and $p:E\rightarrow G$ is a surjective homomorphism such that $Im(i)=Ker(p)$.

Denote by $\mathscr{E}:F\xrightarrow{i} E\xrightarrow{p} G$ the extension $\mathscr{E}=(E,i,p)$ of $G$ by $F$.

> Let $\mathscr{E}:F\xrightarrow{i} E\xrightarrow{p} G$ be an extension
>   of G by a commutative group $F$. The group $E$ operates on $F$ by
>   inner automorphisms, this operation is trivial on the image of $F$ and hence
>   defines an operation of $G$ on $F$.

What is going on here? Specifically, what is the homomorphism corresponding to the action of $E$  on $F$ by inner automorphisms?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $F$ is isomorphic to $i(F)$, and since $i(F)$ is the kernel of a morphism, it is normalin $E$. Thus, for every $x\in E$, conjugation by $x$ is an action on $i(F)$, and hence on $F$ via $i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just answered a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3460077/constructing-a-group-action-from-a-group-extension-a-section), but I will phrase it again somewhat more quickly. If you want any more details, please comment and I'll be happy to explain further.

Again, I will write the extension as

$$0 \to K \xrightarrow{i} G \xrightarrow{p} Q \to 0$$

because I think using $K$ for the kernel and $Q$ for quotient helps keep terminology straight.

In the linked question, we required a splitting $s : Q \to G$ in order to define our action of $Q$ on $K$. In this question, we are able to remove that assumption. The price we pay is that we must assume $K$ is abelian. Why is that true? Let's see:

---

Here is the snappy proof given by Bourbaki:

Define $\gamma_g(k) : K \to K$ by $\gamma_g(k) = gkg^{-1}$ as before. Now, since $K$ is abelian, notice

$$\gamma_k(k') = k k' k^{-1} = k'$$

This tells us that $\gamma_{-} : G \to \text{Aut}(K)$ (the function taking $g$ to $\gamma_g$) has $\gamma_k = \text{Id}$ for each $k \in K$, and so $\gamma_{-}$ descends to the quotient $G/K$ by the universal property of the quotient. Since $G/K \cong Q$, the claim follows.

---

Let's unpack that a little bit. We know $G/K \cong Q$, so we know each $q \in Q$ is isomorphic to $g_q K \in G/K$ for some $g_q \in G$. Now we define our action by

$$\tau_q(k) = g_q k g_q^{-1}$$

Again, if you want to be extra crystal clear, we should actually define it as

$$\tau'_q(k) = i^{-1} \left ( g_q i(k) g_q^{-1}\right)$$

but nobody has time for that.

All we have to do now is check that $\tau_q$ is well defined. What could go wrong if we picked $g_q'$ as a coset representative instead of $g_q$?

Well, $g_q' g_q^{-1} \in K$, so $g_q' = k g_q$. Now we see:

$$g_q' k' g_q^{-1} = (k g_q) k' (k g_q)^{-1} = k (g_q k' g_q^{-1}) k^{-1} = g_q k' g_q^{-1}$$

where the last equality comes from $K$ being abelian (and $g_q k' g_q^{-1} \in K$).

---

As an aside, you can drop the hypothesis that $K$ is abelian AND the hypothesis of a splitting $s : Q \to G$ if you are willing to put in some extra work. I won't go into it here, but it is a very interesting (and useful!) topic.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what you meant by "...$\gamma_{-}$ descends to the quotient $G/K$ by the universal property of the quotient"? Thank you.

Comment: Absolutely! The "universal property of the quotient" is some category-theory lingo that unifies how we expect constructions called "quotients" to behave. Quotients are characterized by how we define functions out of them. Indeed functions $f : A/K \to B$ are in bijection with functions $\tilde{f} : A \to B$ with the bonus property that $\tilde{f}(K) = 0$.

Comment: Why is this useful, though? In our example, we want a function $Q \to \text{Aut}(K)$, and we know $Q = G/K$. So, since we know functions from $G/K \to \text{Aut}(K)$ are in bijection with functions from $G \to \text{Aut}(K)$ such that all of $K$ is mapped to the identity, it suffices to find such a function $G \to \text{Aut}(K)$. Thankfully $\gamma_{-} : G \to \text{Aut}(K)$ works! Since $\gamma_k = \text{id}$ for every $k$ in $K$, we know that $\gamma_-$ induces a function $\gamma'_- : G/K \to \text{Aut}(K)$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Actually going through the proof of the bijective correspondence is basically unwinding the snappy version of the proof and the second version that I talked about above. http://sites.millersville.edu/bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/universal-property-of-the-quotient/universal-property-of-the-quotient.pdf -- Here's a PDF on the topic that goes into the proof rather in depth. It's a useful thing to keep in your back pocket ^_^

Comment: superb!-thank you!

Comment: @HallaSurvivor: Can you comment on the "aside"? How can we get an action if we drop the section and the Abelian assumption?

Comment: @Isomorphism -- there is a theory of  "nonabelian extensions" where we look at extensions where both the kernel and quotient are possibly nonabelian. Given any nonabelian extension which is not split, we won't have a group-theoretic section either. The theory is less clean, though, because we don't (directly) have the tools of group cohomology to work with. You can read more in chapter IV.6 of Brown's _Cohomology of Groups_, and this book also references some other sources which cover the topic in more detail (but which I haven't read)

Comment: "Given any nonabelian extension which is not split, we won't have a group-theoretic section either." I was interested in this case. Thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

$i$ is injective and the image $i(F)$ is a normal subgroup. Any element $e\in E$ stabilizes this subgroup, so if $f\in F$ then there is an $f'$ such that $ei(f)e^{-1}=i(f')$. This means that the action of $e$ on $f$ yields $f'$. These aren't inner automorphisms of $F$, but the inner automorphisms of $E$ act on the image of $F$, which pulls back to $F$.